# Alguno expresion que elimine %20 de un string javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, urlencoding

Ejemplo con javascript

```
var name = "Pedro Canche";
var newname = name.replace("%20", " ");
```

> salida: Pedro Canche

pero cuando cuando es asi:

```
var name = "Pedro Misael Canche Angulo";
var newname = name.replace("%20", " ");
```

> salida: Pedro Misael%Canche%20Angulo

Espero ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6):

La pregunta no deja claro si quiere añadir o quitar los `%20`, pero me parece un tema interesante, así que respondo de una manera global:

Hay varios métodos nativos en Javascript que se encargan de esas transformaciones:

```js
let baseURL='http://www.example.com/';
let otraURL='http://www.otra.com/'
let nombreFichero='espacio y carácter.txt';

//para codificar quitando caracteres especiales en una URL
console.log('Componiendo la URL:', encodeURI (baseURL+nombreFichero));

//para codificar parámetros, no la URI entera:
let param=encodeURIComponent(nombreFichero);
console.log('con parámetro:',baseURL + '?fichero=' + param );
//Aquí se ve la diferencia
param=encodeURIComponent(otraURL);
console.log('con una URL como parámetro:',baseURL + '?search=' + param );

console.log('Obteniendo nombre original: ', decodeURIComponent(param));
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con

```
newname = name.replace(/%20/g," ");
```

se me paso colocar el modificador `g` para indicar que remplace todas las coincidencias encontradas sobre la cadena

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
newname = name.replace(/%20/g," ");
```

con esto debería funcionarte correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tú estás usando, se llama encoding, basicamente el encoding te permite utilizar un formato de un caracter en algo transmisible por "internet"

Acá estás utilizando ASCII encoding,

No deberías utilizar replace, deberías usar la función de escapar estos caracteres si así lo quieres:

en Javascript:

```
var name = "Pedro Misael%20Canche Angulo";

console.log(escape(name))

salida: Pedro%20Misael%2520Canche%20Angulo



console.log(unescape(name))

salida: Pedro Misael Canche Angulo
```

Comment: `unescape()` quedó obsoleta hace más de 15 años